# What replaced nrow(compute()) in dplyr 0.5.0?

Tags: r, dplyr

I used to be able to do `nrow(compute())` before `collect()` as a quick sanity check ahead of hitting the database -- and the local hard drive -- with a huge data transfer. Now this is no longer an option. How do you tell how many rows has a remote table generated by `compute()` in dplyr 0.5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can accomplish your sanity check by:

assuming ungrouped table in `db` named `src`:

`tbl(db, src) %>% summarise(nrow = n())`

in `dplyr_0.5.0`. Note that this returns a `tbl` instead of an `int` though.